# Preserving Pixel & Tonic Fieldtype Settings After Migrating to EE2

Tags: matrix, playa, wygwam

I'm in the process of migrating a site from EE1 to EE2. I successfully upgraded to EE2, but all the P&T addons (Matrix, Wygwam, Playa & Field Pack) seemed to default to either `text`, `select`, `ftype_id_X`, or `wysiwyg` under the `field_type` column.

How can I successfully update and preserve the fieldtype settings? I didn't see any docs specific to migration with these addons.

I noticed a `ff_settings` column in the `exp_channel_fields` table, but `NULL` value in the `field_settings` column?

When I go to edit a field group, I get theses errors (see attached). They Wygwam fields are blank in the type column?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

#### Wygwam Update

Wygwam fields were easy to update, I just ran a query in the DB:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_fields SET field_type = 'wygwam' WHERE field_type = 'wysiwyg'
```

#### Playa Update

All playa fields are text inputs right now that, which have data stored like:

```
[101] Title 1[102] Title 2
```

If I update the field settings to Playa with the correct filters, no entries are selected in the right pane of the multi-select.

Comment: Siebird, what steps have you taken in regards to upgrading your add-ons for this site?  Have you visited their add-on settings pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of our EE2 add-ons include a script that gets run during installation, which will attempt to determine if its EE1 counterpart used to be installed, and migrate all of the old settings and data.

So all that you should need to do is upgrade to EE2 and then install the EE2 versions of our add-ons.

If that didn’t work for you, chances are you tampered with the old exp_ff_fieldtypes table, or edited your field settings before installing the add-ons. I'd suggest that you re-attempt the EE2 upgrade, and go straight to installing the P&T add-ons before doing anything else.

Comment: I'll give this another shot. However, I did notice the site is running  Playa 2.1.2, which has the `exp_playa_relationship` table. Currently there is only two rows in that table. I'm thinking there might be an issue there since there is a ton of relationships still stored in the native `exp_relationships` table. Any ideas on how to migrate those over to the new playa table before I upgrade? The only versions of Playa I have are 4.x w/ 3.x

Comment: I successfully got the fieldtypes working after my second attempt. Still having issues with Playa getting the relationships though.

Comment: That exp_playa_relationships table didn’t come until Playa 4. Most likely it was left over from when you first installed Playa 4, and so the second time around, Playa saw that it was there and decided to abort the EE1 upgrade script rather than chance deleting data. You’ll need to drop that table before installing Playa 4. Sorry, I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Ok, so just delete that table and run it again?

Comment: Eh, you’ll probably have to restore your EE1 DB again (but this time delete all of your tables first, so there’s no chance of any other EE2 tables sticking around), re-upgrade to EE2, and re-install the add-ons.

Comment: Alright. 4th times a charm, right?